# Rails ExecJS configure Nodejs on specific directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, execjs

I'm using Rails 4 on Ubuntu 13.04, and I'd like to configure my rails application to use a compiled Nodejs installed on another directory, without specifying a system environment variable for Node.
Maybe, using

```
ENV[EXECJS_RUNTIME] = /path/to/compiled/node
```

would be a clue, but I don't know how to use it and where.
This is because I prefer to use a compiled Nodejs without changing the Ubuntu environment variables.
Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

ENV['PATH'] = ENV['PATH'] + ':/path/to/compiled'